# Outlook 2013: How to display message headers in reading pane?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Using Outlook 2013, I'd like to be able to view all header fields (RFC5322, not what Outlook calls headers) of a message that I preview in the reading pane.

Is there a setting, an option or a 3rd party add-on that do this or is there such a thing that can at least provide a right-click menu?

Edit: I do not need the raw message in whole, just the headers.

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I view all header fields of a message that I preview in the reading pane?

The following procedure will set this up for you.

**Warning**

- The PST file zize Will Increase as Outlook will store the message source in addition to storing the message's content
- This means future emails will take up roughly double the space.

> **Make Available the Complete Message Source in Outlook**
>
> To set up Outlook so you can see the complete source of emails:
>
> - Press Windows-R
> - Type "regedit".
> - Hit Enter.
> - For Outlook 2016:
>
>   - Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\­­Software\­­Microsoft\­­Office\­­16.0\­­Outlook\­­Options\­­Mail.
> - For Outlook 2013:
>
>   - Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\­­Software\­­Microsoft\­­Office\­­15.0\­­Outlook\­­Options\­­Mail.
> - For Outlook 2010:
>
>   - Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\­­Software\­­Microsoft\­­Office\­­14.0\­­Outlook\­­Options\­­Mail.
> - For Outlook 2007:
>
>   - Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\­­Software\­­Microsoft\­­Office\­­12.0\­­Outlook\­­Options\­­Mail.
> - For Outlook 2003
>
>   - Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\­­Software\­­Microsoft\­­Office\­­11.0\­­Outlook\­­Options\­­Mail.
> - Select Edit | New | DWord from the menu.
>
>   - Select DWORD (32-bit) Value with 32-bit Office.
>   - Use DWORD (64-bit) Value with 64-bit Office (which is unlikely).
> - Type "SaveAllMIMENotJustHeaders".
> - Hit Enter.
> - Double-click the newly created SaveAllMIMENotJustHeaders value.
> - Type "1".
> - Click OK.
> - Close the registry editor.
> - Restart Outlook if it has been running.
>
> **See the Complete Source of a Message in Outlook**
>
> Now you can retrieve the source of newly retrieved POP messages
>   (editing the SaveAllMIMENotJustHeaders value does not restore the
>   complete message source for emails that were already in Outlook):
>
> - Open the desired message in its own window.
> - Double-click the email.
> - Click FILE.
> - Make sure the Info category is open.
> - Now click Properties.
> - Find the source to the email under Internet headers:.
> - Click Close.

Source [How to View the Complete Message Source in Outlook](https://www.lifewire.com/view-complete-message-source-outlook-1173713)

Comment: I can see the mail headers using the procedure you outline (File-Info-Properties-Internet Headers) even without the registry key. My goal is to display those "Internet Headers" in the "reading pane" directly.

Answer (score 1):

The following Macro displays the headers in a new mail message window (can't use a msgbox because of size limitations):

```
Sub ViewInternetHeader()
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem, olMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strheader As String

    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        strheader = GetInetHeaders(olItem)

        Set olMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With olMsg 
            .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
            .Body = strheader
            .Display
        End With
    Next
    Set olMsg = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetInetHeaders(olkMsg As Outlook.MailItem) As String
    ' Purpose: Returns the internet headers of a message.'
    ' Written: 4/28/2009'
    ' Author:  BlueDevilFan'
    ' //techniclee.wordpress.com/
    ' Outlook: 2007'
    Const PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E"
    Dim olkPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    Set olkPA = olkMsg.PropertyAccessor
    GetInetHeaders = olkPA.GetProperty(PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS)
    Set olkPA = Nothing
End Function
```

Source: https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/outlooks-internet-headers/